# Who to add spring scheduled job cron into application yml file?

Tags: java, spring, cron

I have a scheduled task in spring and it is working good.

```
    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
    public void scheduledjob() {

    }
```

What I want to do is put that cron parameter into the application.yml file. I have found the solution on internet for application.properties but I want to use application.yml but don't worked with it before. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You need to put the property in application.yml file just like in application.properties.

This is how my application.yml file looks like:

```
cronexpression : '0 34 13 * * ?'
```

And the scheduler looks like:

```
@Component
class TestScheduler{

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cronexpression}")
    public void scheduledjob() {
        System.out.println("Scheduler is running");
    }

}
```

This is the output. You can change the cronexpression according to your need.

[image]